# revoking mysql table level privileges

Tags: mysql, permissions, table

I have a mysql user account who has following Global privileges

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER,
SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW,
CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT,
TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'maintenance'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password';
```

I need to revoke insert, delete or update privileges on the certain tables  for this user. So, I tried this:

```
mysql> REVOKE INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON  Hotels.AllHotels FROM 'user'@'host';
```

An I am seeing the following error

> ERROR 1147 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'user' on host 'host' on table 'AllHotels'

I am performing the above actions as the mysql root user.

Could someone help please?

Comment: Mysql is a bit retarded sometimes,read the comments:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/revoke.html GRANT and REVOKE have to match.

Comment: Make that 2M bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script to help you create the grant script syntax :
Run a root od mysql admin user.

```
  select 'grant all privileges on ', table_name, 'to 
someuser@somehost;' from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'database name' and 
table_name not in ('table without access', 'table without access');
```

This will create an output that you can run after.

**Just to replicate the error :**

```
mysql> grant select on BASE_BIB.* to test123@'%' identified by 'test';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use BASE_BIB;
Database changed
mysql> show tables ;
```

**Now revoke select from a table form inside the BASE_BIB database:**

```
mysql> revoke select on BASE_BIB.users from test123@'%';
ERROR 1147 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'test123'
```

on host '%' on table 'users'

**No the right way to do it :**

```
mysql> grant select on BASE_BIB.users to test123@'%' identified by 'test';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> revoke select on BASE_BIB.users from test123@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**No error now !!**

Managing access in mysql can be quite dificult !!

Once you gave him database.* you cannot revoke access for an object that is in that class.
MySQL doesn't expand the Hotels.* wildcard to the individual tables
 The permissions tables store the granted permissions. Therefore, since you didn't actually grant anything on Hotels.AllHotels , there's nothing for MySQL to revoke. 
In this case you need to do it granular form the start !

**Remove all privileges on database, table, column levels, etccc.**

- Grant privileges to EACH table, except 'you choose'.
- Grant privilege to specified fields in table 'you choose'.